# Tradingview - “Go to Date” using pine-script

Tags: pine-script

Is there a way to move the view automatically to a specific historical date? Basically doing the same thing as the "Go to..." button, but automatically with a script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can't move the bars on a chart from a script.

Not-what-you-want-but-loosely-related: We are currently speccing a feature that would allow script authors to provide the user with a means of selecting a specific bar (date-time) on a chart to provide a date-time input into a script: https://trello.com/c/H8rcP1TE